# Google maps embed error in firefox

Tags: google-maps, firefox, google-maps-embed

I am using google maps Embed code to integrate multipin locations of a map.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zsjXv3NS8g6Y.krO7DAwRdcZk" height="480" width="640"></iframe>
```

The map is rendering properly in all other browsers with cross origin reference error.(even in IE7 with old version warning)

This is the message I see on chrome and IE

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mapsengine&passive=1209600…p=https://www.google.com/maps/d/gen204?a%3D58%26width%3D640%26height%3D480. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.google.com' is therefore not allowed access.

but in firefox theres a different error and map does not load.

> ReferenceError: _startApp is not defined
>   https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zsjXv3NS8g6Y.krO7DAwRdcZk
>   Line 7

This is an embed code to which i can't modify. Any solutions?

EDIT: iframe is loading without map but clearly script in the iframe is breaking causing this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was with the security certificates of firefox due to proxy used in organisation.
I installed the security certificates from my organisation and the map started working properly.

steps.

1. Go to options
2. Advanced
3. Certificates
4. View certificates.
5. Import and install your certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following step to `reset firefox` and see if it works:

The `Reset Firefox` feature can fix many issues by restoring Firefox to its factory default state while saving your essential information. Note: `This will cause you to lose any Extensions, Open websites, and some Preferences.`

To `Reset Firefox` do the following:

Go to Firefox > Help > Troubleshooting Information.

1. Click the "Reset Firefox" button.
2. Firefox will close and reset. After Firefox is done, it will show a window with the information that is imported.
3. Click Finish.
4. Firefox will open with all factory defaults applied.